# Ethernet and Wi-fi don't work Linux Mint 19.2

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, ethernet, nomodeset

I just installed Linux Mint (first time using Linux) on my HP G7 255. I don't have experience with programming or Linux in general, but for over an hour I can't connect to the internet. I have to say at this point that in the booting process in order not to have a black screen I changed "quiet splash" to `nomodeset` (no idea what are those, but it worked, read that it has to do with the drivers).

I would really appreciate some help here, I read about 10 different forum discussions on this topic but I didn't understand a lot.

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:0e:3c:f0:75:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

# dmesg | grep fail
ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.GPP2.BCM5] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/dswload-210)
ACPI Error: 1 table load failures, 12 successful (20170831/tbxfload-246)
ACPI Error: [WLVD] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)
[    0.137990] ACPI Error: [WLVD] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)
[    0.233009] ACPI Error: [WLVD] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)
[    0.328972] ACPI Error: [WLVD] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)
```

Comment: Please add output of ```ip a``` to your question and check ```sudo dmesg``` for ethernet / wi-fi related error messages.

Comment: @dirdi I didn't get the first thing you said about ip a. Also the second one what is it about?

Comment: Under Linux you can do most thinks faster using a terminal. Open one (The Ctrl+Alt+t shortcut works for most distributions, or search the "start menu" for it), type in the two commands I mentioned above (one at a time), hit return and paste their output to the end of your question.

Comment: thank you! do I put them exactly as you typed em here? And what exactly is "ip a" ?

Comment: The second command is huge, I don't even know how to put it here, as the linux laptop doesnt connect to the internet.

Comment: I made a doc file with the output of the commands ( its 22 pages, and so many characters to put it here(

Comment: Well done so far. Just paste the complete output of ```ip -a```, as well as lines from ```sudo dmesg``` containing "err" or "fail" plus some surrounding lines as context to the end of your question. Then we will probably be able to help you.

Comment: I uploaded them, the word "failure" appeared 6 times after the command "sudo dmseg"